# Первичный ключ таблицы InnoDB по умолчанию MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysqli, innodb

Если при создании таблицы явно не прописываем первичный ключ (с автоинкрементом), то mySQL создает его по умолчанию "скрытно".

Вопрос: какого типа создается этот скрытный первичный ключ INT, BIGINT?

Answer (score 0):

Вообще реализация данного индекса может отличаться от версии к версии. Данный индекс зачастую по способу хранения является кластерным (или калстеризованным), т.е. в отличии от классического хранит не только сам индекс, но и данные строки. В мануале описание типа отсутствует, говорится только о том, что сам индекс 6 байтовый, уникальный, имеет наименование GEN_CLUST_INDEX и растет по мере роста таблицы

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-index-types.html